# just looking for an xml tag and showing on the page using php

Tags: php, xml

I have an xml file, and would like specific items of this xml, I can bring all the item tags to the page, through the code:

```
<?php
    $feed =file_get_contents('https://brasil.elpais.com/rss/brasil/portada_completo.xml'); 


     $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

     foreach($rss->channel->item as $noticia) {
        echo '<p><a href="'.$noticia->link.'" title="'. $noticia->title .'">'.$noticia->title.''.$noticia->description.'</a></p>';
}       

?>
```

the idea is to bring only one of the  tags, the xml array print is:
[Array xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anEsW.jpg)

I wanted to ask for help to bring this specific tag, and if someone knows how to randomly interact between two or more xml files.

I would like to for example show on the page the first item tag of the first xml, then the first item tag of the second xml, and after the fourth item tag of the first xml and progress that way

or the last post of the date of each xml file

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Just the first? What are the criteria? What do you mean with randomly interact between two or more xml files?

Comment: I would like to for example show on the page the first item tag of the first xml, then the first item tag of the second xml, and dps the fourth item tag of the first xml and progress that way

Comment: sorry about my english

Comment: @BrunoClementin then please clarify it in the question.